# onPageScrolled Method in ViewPagerNot being Called

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement `SlidingMenu` by jfeinstein and work with `ViewPager`.

However, I can not get the `onPageScrolled` method to be called.  Then I realized, they weren't being overriding and when I added that, it says must override a superclass method.

Here is setup:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                smenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                break;
            default:
                smenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
                break;
            }

        }

    });
```

Can anyone see why `onPageScrolled` isn't being called, and if so, what is missing?  (I've toasted the position variable to prove this).

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I need to call `TitlePageIndicator`'s version of these methods, not `ViewPager's`